# Why does google map use Canvas to make distance measurement not SVG?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, canvas, svg

I use chrome debug tool to compare google map and other maps.
I found for the distance measurement function, google map use canvas to draw the path and some others use SVG.
I assume that maybe this is because canvas is faster. But SVG have many good parts for drawing the path.
Is there any other reasons?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Every SVG element is a DOM element and having 10,000+ SVG paths causes a massive slowdown compared to Canvas. So one possibility is the performance of it.

But originally Android did not render/support SVG. That's probably the real reason why Google chose to use Canvas.

Today, Tablet Android (3.0+) has SVG support but 1.0-2.3 do not.

Comment: Thanks a lot! And for the performance reason ,if I draw a line in both  canvas and SVG, is SVG paths will trigger re-flow? and how about canvas? re-paint only?

Comment: Once all SVG DOM objects are loaded things aren't *too* bad. Both will be fairly slow on redrawing all 10,000 objects but there are is far more room for improving the performance of the Canvas one.

Comment: @SimonSarris I'm keen to know regarding being slow on redrawing say 10,000 objects, how Canvas can improve on this? Thanks!